# Как найти и объединить все дублирующиеся записи о человеке в одну

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Из csv файла получены данные следующего вида:

```
lastname,firstname,surname,organization,position,phone,email
Паньшин,Алексей,Владимирович,,,Минфин,,+7(495)748-49-73,1248@minfin.ru
Лагунцов,Иван,Алексеевич,,,Минфин,,+7(495)913-11-11 доб.0792,
Лагунцов,Иван,,,,Ivan.Laguntcov@minfin.ru
```

Надо найти дублирующие записи и объединить, а лишнюю строку удалить:

```
Паньшин,Алексей,Владимирович,Минфин,,+7(495)748-49-73,1248@minfin.ru
Лагунцов,Иван,Алексеевич,Минфин,,+7(495)913-11-11 доб.0792,Ivan.Laguntcov@minfin.ru
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать.

PS. Данные взяты с открытых источников

Comment: Как узнать что две записи про одного человека? `Иванов,Иван,Иванович`, `Иванов,Иван,Петрович`, `Иванов,Иван,` - это сколько людей?

Comment: Извиняюсь за не полный вопрос. Если ФИ или, можно, ФИО совпадает, то считается, что это один и тот же человек. Одинаковые люди могут быть не только в соседствующих строках.

Comment: В списке есть `Иванов,Иван,Иванович` и `Иванов,Иван,Петрович`. Вы встретили `Иванов,Иван,` (без отчества), то этот (без отчества) кто он? Иванович? Петрович? Ещё кто-то?

Comment: Вы верно рассуждаете, правильнее сверять ФИО, но в этом задании надо сверять ФИ, так как идентичные ФИ будет только в 2-х экземплярах. Будет Иванов Иван Иванович и Иванов Иван, а вот Петровича не будет :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из вашей задачи, предполагаю, что данные, которые вы указали, находятся в формате *str*. Если две последние строчки об одном и том же человеке, то воспользуйтесь модулем *collections*:

```
from collections import OrderedDict


def remove_duplicates(list_: list) -> list:
    k = 0
    while k < len(list_) - 1:
        for list1, list2 in zip(list_[k], list_[k + 1]):
            if list1 == list2:
                new_list = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(list_[k] + list_[k + 1]))
                list_.remove(list_[k + 1])
                list_.remove(list_[k])
                list_.append(new_list)
            break
        k += 1
    return list_


contact_list = [
    ['lastname', 'firstname', 'surname', 'organization', 'position', 'phone', 'email'],
    ['Паньшин', 'Алексей', 'Владимирович', '', '', 'Минфин', '', '+7(495)748-49-73', '1248@minfin.ru'],
    ['Лагунцов', 'Иван', 'Алексеевич', '', '', 'Минфин', '', '+7(495)913-11-11 доб.0792', ''],
    ['Лагунцов', 'Иван', '', '', '', 'Ivan.Laguntcov@minfin.ru']]

unique_data_list = remove_duplicates(contact_list)
print(unique_data_list)
```

Comment: Вы предполагаете что дубликаты всегда рядом?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy валидное замечание. Тут я исхожу из данных и предполагаю, что имя и фамилия говорят о том, что это один и тот же человек. Если уникальным будет телефон или емейл, то функцию можно чуть изменить, и все будет ок.

Comment: Добрый вечер. Извиняюсь за не полный вопрос. Все правильно, все данные в формате str и в том виде как вы указали. Если ФИ или, можно, ФИО совпадает, то считается, что это один и тот же человек. Одинаковые люди могут быть не только в соседствующих строках. Функция и модуль, который вы предложили, отлично решают мой вопрос, нужно будет только немного доработать. Спасибо большое.